# How do I make the virtual keyboard enter text into a textbox in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, virtual-keyboard

I have a windows forms application containing a button and a textbox. At "button_click_event" this code is executed:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

The keyboard shows, yet no text appears on the textbox as I type on said keyboard.

Comment: Make sure the textbox is focused, then change to the keyboard and type something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that the on screen keyboard is sending information to the Focused Control which in your case is the Button that initiated the Keyboard. Try setting focus to to your textbox after creating the keyboard.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
    //SetFocus to your TextBox here
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

To close it do something like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk");
    if (procs.Length != 0)
        procs[0].Kill();

}
```

Comment: yes..this is working fine,,sir but i have one doubt,,this command(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe"); actually enabling Virtual key bord?

Comment: @user3252014 It is what you need to do to run the OnScreen Keyboard. The keyboard is an external application therefore you need to use Process.Start to run it.

Comment: @user3252014 There is nothing to edit in the code, the virtual keyboard sends its data to what ever is focused at the time. The code that I gave will work and answers your question.

Comment: sir,,how i can close this keybord

Comment: You can either use the Close Button on the Keyboard or you can Kill the process that you started I will put the code for the latter in my answer. I actually wondered if you would ask this.